# Unexpected behaviour for C++ type conversion operator for rvalue and lvalue instance of some type

Tags: c++, casting, rvalue-reference

I have a question regarding cast operator for some type which has overloads for actual instance as a rvalue and lvalue. I put my question inside the code sample, where I expected something else than actual result.

Maybe someone can enlighten me why it is done as it is done?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    std::vector<int> m_value;

    Foo & add(int i)
    {
        m_value.emplace_back(i);
    }
    std::vector<int> const & get() const &
    {
        std::cout << "lvalue cast\n";
        return m_value;
    }
    std::vector<int> get() &&
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue cast\n";
        return std::move(m_value);
    }

    operator std::vector<int> const &() const &
    {
        std::cout << "lvalue cast\n";
        return m_value;
    }
    operator std::vector<int>() &&
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue cast\n";
        return std::move(m_value);
    }
};

Foo make_foo()
{
    Foo ret;
    ret.m_value.emplace_back(0);
    ret.m_value.emplace_back(1);
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    { // cast
        std::cout << "cast operator\n";
        Foo foo = make_foo();
        std::vector<int> foo_rvalue = make_foo(); // rvalue cast
        std::vector<int> const & foo_lvalue = foo; // lvalue cast
        std::vector<int> foo_move_assign;
        //foo_move_assign = std::move(foo); // ambigous or lvalue cast (onlinegdb.com), but I expected rvalue cast
        std::vector<int> foo_move_ctor = std::move(foo); // rvalue cast
        std::vector<int> const &foo_move_to_cref = std::move(foo); // lvalue cast, but I expected rvalue cast
    }
    { // get
        std::cout << "get method\n";
        Foo foo = make_foo();
        std::vector<int> foo_rvalue = make_foo().get(); // rvalue cast
        std::vector<int> const & foo_lvalue = foo.get(); // lvalue cast
        std::vector<int> foo_move_assign;
        foo_move_assign = std::move(foo).get(); // rvalue cast
        std::vector<int> foo_move_ctor = std::move(foo).get(); // rvalue cast
        std::vector<int> const &foo_move_to_cref = std::move(foo).get(); // rvalue cast
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can check results via https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Further question would be how to get behaviour like I expected.

**Edit**: put `static_cast<std::vector<int>>(...)` to move_assign variant.

**Edit**: removed `static_cast<std::vector<int>>(...)` from move_assign variant and adapted comment/problem.

**Edit**: added `get()` methods to `Foo` with same functionality as cast operator and extended sample code in `main` accordingly.

Comment: I observe a different effect in the first case - an ambiguous overload: https://godbolt.org/z/evnqMG. Moreover, `foo_move_assign = std::move(foo).operator std::vector<int>();` works: https://godbolt.org/z/bv1eca. This: `foo_move_assign = std::move(foo).operator std::vector<int> const & ();` works as well.

Comment: interesting that gdb is not cpmplaining ...

Comment: explicitly specifying operator is actually not feasible in practice I would say. That should be properly deduced by compiler, or do I miss something?

Comment: BTW, note that the first conversion operator may be called even for an rvalue of type `Foo`, therefore, for `std::move(foo)`.

Comment: why that? what is then the point of having overloads for lvalue and rvalue variants?

Comment: Const l-value reference can always bind both rvalues and lvalues. If you provide both overlaods, rvalue reference will have higher priority for rvalues. However, in your case, there is no overload. You have two different cast operators (to different types). That's the source of the ambiguity I guess. Check this case: https://godbolt.org/z/aPW7cs. If you change the first cast operator also to "plain" `int`, it starts working as expected.

Comment: I see. But the whole idea is to have a special cast for rvalue references, to avoid dangling references to object with is not there anymore. Other option would to to always make copy cast but that might be expensive for larger types.

Comment: I see your point. It an interesting problem. But I don't know now how to avoid the ambiguity with implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

The `static_cast` undoes the effects of the move. Here's how `std::move` equivalent could be implemented:

```
static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)
```

What you're doing is rolling it back:

```
static_cast<T>(static_cast<typename std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>(t))
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast):

> static_cast<new_type>(expression) returns the imaginary variable Temp initialized as if by new_type Temp(expression);

That imaginary *variable* Temp is of a value type (not reference), and it has a name (it's a variable), thus I don't think it can be expected to behave as proposed...

As for how to make it work as you expect? Such implicit conversions are evil, and I imagine at the moment that the best you can do is:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::vector<int> m_value;

    operator std::vector<int>() const &
    {
        std::cout << "lvalue cast\n";
        return m_value;
    }
    operator std::vector<int>() &&
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue cast\n";
        return std::move(m_value);
    }
};
```

Comment: ok, I added this due to hint of @Daniel Langr. Do you know why it is ambigous without the cast. I would have expected that after std::move foo is an rvalue reference and hence using the rvalue variant of the cast operator...